# Form input problem when showing one input per time (Vue)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js

So I want to create a form in a web application (using Vue.js) where I show one form field at a time. As soon as the input is filled in correctly and the 'Next' button is pressed, it needs to show the next input in the form.

My form:

```
<form class="account-form">
    <div class="input-field" v-if="formCount === 1">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input id="email" required v-bind:class="{wrong : wrongInput}" type="email" name="email" @blur="triggerCheck"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field" v-if="formCount === 2">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" required v-bind:class="{wrong : wrongInput}" type="text" name="name" @blur="triggerCheck"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field" v-if="formCount === 3">
        <label for="address">Adress</label>
        <input id="address" required v-bind:class="{wrong : wrongInput}" type="text" name="address" @blur="triggerCheck"/>
        <label for="number">Nr</label>
        <input id="number" required v-bind:class="{wrong : wrongInput}" type="text" name="number" @blur="triggerCheck"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field" v-if="formCount === 4">
        <label for="zipcode">Zip code</label>
        <input id="zipcode" required v-bind:class="{wrong : wrongInput}" type="text" name="zipcode" @blur="triggerCheck"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field" v-if="formCount === 5">
        <label for="place">Place</label>
        <input id="place" required v-bind:class="{wrong : wrongInput}" type="text" name="place" @blur="triggerCheck"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field" v-if="formCount === 6">
        <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
        <input id="phone" required v-bind:class="{wrong : wrongInput}" type="number" name="phone" @blur="triggerCheck"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Every time the 'Next' button is pressed, `formCount` is incremented by one.

The problem is that when I enter a value in the first input and press next, the label for the next input shows but the value entered in the first input also appears in the next input. So I enter an e-mail address, I press 'Next', and the next input is Name where the input should be empty, but it shows the e-mail address I filled in in the previous input, so somehow the input inherits the previous value.

Putting `value=""` inside the input element won't make any difference unfortunately.

The `triggerCheck()` function (which fires on focus loss):

```
triggerCheck: function () {
    if (document.querySelector('form').checkValidity() === false) {
      this.wrongInput = true
      return false
    } else {
      this.wrongInput = false
      return true
    }
  }
```

I can't find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the why and how about this problem.

Vue.js reuses elements to be as efficient as possible. There can be worked around this by either using unique key values *or* in my case, using `v-show` instead of `v-if`.

See [Vue.js conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key)